# getting corresponding value of an attribute from an NSXMLElement

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsxmlparser

How can i get the corresponding value of an attribute of an NSXMlelement object from a self constructed NSXMLNode.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[element attributeForName:@"name"] stringValue]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your struct type is a NSXMLElement then I use:

NSString *valueInTag = [[element elementForName:@"name"] stringValue];